# 2 Sample KS-Test. CDF or PDF as input?

Tags: python, testing, kolmogorov-smirnov

I implemented the KS-Test to test which Distributions are better fitting together. At this moment, I gave the CDFs as input, because the standard KS-Test involves computing the maximum difference between the CDFs of the function. I just wanted to know if this is the right way to do it. Or should I use the PDFS as input? The statistics values and p-values seem good for me. With the critical value of the KS-Test i can chose which Hypothesis tests I should not reject.

## Code example

```
gammafit = stats.gamma.fit(h4)  
pdf_gamma = stats.gamma.pdf(lnspc, *gammafit)  
cdf_gamma = stats.gamma.cdf(lnspc, *gammafit) 
plt.plot(lnspc, pdf_gamma, label="Gamma")

gamma_kstest999 = stats.ks_2samp(np.cumsum(n4), cdf_gamma)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the pdfs as input. ks_2samp takes as input the pdfs and creates the cdfs inside the code. According to the function source code:

```
data1 = np.sort(data1)
    data2 = np.sort(data2)
    n1 = data1.shape[0]
    n2 = data2.shape[0]
    data_all = np.concatenate([data1, data2])
    cdf1 = np.searchsorted(data1, data_all, side='right') / (1.0*n1)
    cdf2 = np.searchsorted(data2, data_all, side='right') / (1.0*n2)
    d = np.max(np.absolute(cdf1 - cdf2))
    # Note: d absolute not signed distance
    en = np.sqrt(n1 * n2 / float(n1 + n2))
    try:
        prob = distributions.kstwobign.sf((en + 0.12 + 0.11 / en) * d)
    except:
        prob = 1.0

    return Ks_2sampResult(d, prob)
```

The cdf1 and cdf2 variables represent the produced cumulative distributions.